# Split string without split function in c

Tags: c

So I'm writing a program that takes a persons name and splits it into their first and last name so for example if you enter JonSnow it should print:
First: Jon
Last: Snow

This is the code, please ignore the comments, I was testing a bunch of different ways to do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()    
{   
    char name[50],first[25],last[25];
    int i;

    printf("What is your name? ");
    scanf("%s",name);

    strcpy(first," ");
    strcpy(last," ");
    for(i=0;i<strlen(name);i++){
        strcat(first,name[i]);              //for(j=i+1;strlen(name);j++){
        if(name[i+1]>=65 && name[i+1]<=90){
            strcat(last,name[i]);
            strcat(last,name[i+1]); 
        }
        //}             
    }

    printf("First name: %s \n",first);
    printf("Last name: %s \n",last);  
}
```

When I run it in the terminal, I get this:

```
What is your name? JonSnow

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What is the problem, please help...

Comment: strcat takes two char* parameters, but you pass in name[i], which is a char.

Comment: `if(name[i+1]>=65 && name[i+1]<=90){` is ok, but [isupper](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isupper) is a lot more readable/directly understandable.

Comment: Just a general comment - assuming there are only 2 capital letters (first one is beginning of first name and second one is beginning of last name) a better algorithm will be:
Iterate over your string to find the index of second capital letter. Then using strncpy, copy the first part until this index (excluding) to `first`, and from this index to the end to `last`.

Comment: You should use a width specifier when using `%s` in `scanf()` to prevent buffer overflow: `scanf("%49s",name);`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is close, you're just messing up how to use strcat trying to add a single character to the end of a string, which it doesn't do.  Perhaps you can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

char name[50],first[25] = {0},last[25] = {0};
int i;

    printf("What is your name? ");
    scanf("%s",name);

    for(i=0;i<strlen(name);i++) {
        if(name[i+1]>=65 && name[i+1]<=90) {
            strncpy(first,name,i+1);
            strcpy(last,&name[i+1]); 
        }
    }
    printf("First name: %s \n",first);
    printf("Last name: %s \n",last);
}
```

strncpy copies the number of characters specified by i+1 into first.

Comment: Without a width specifier in the call to `scanf()`, there is a risk of buffer overflow. Also, if the first or last name is longer than 24 characters, this code writes out of bounds. `i` should be `size_t` since `strlen()` returns a `size_t` value.

Comment: All that is true.  Also, if there are no capital letters in the input, it will crash too.